# lvm data recovery after reinstall

Tags: data

I have an SSD and a HDD on my pc. SSD is for system and HDD is for storing data. I changed my os from debian to ubuntu but I forgot to backup the lvm on my HDD. Of course I lost my data.
  I've tried recreate a new logic volume on it with the same size. But when I run xfs_repair, it shows "Counld not find valid secondary superblock". It seems useless. Since I've created a new logic volume, lvscan solution is also useless. So is there a way that I can restore my data?

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated, we don't really know what happened, and your attempts might not have helped things.

By default, when you re-create Logical Volumes, it will wipe signatures and zero the first 4KiB of data. In other words it makes extra sure no old filesystem will be visible on the newly created LV.

```
   -W|--wipesignatures y|n
          Controls detection and subsequent wiping of signatures on new LVs.

   -Z|--zero y|n
          Controls zeroing of the first 4KiB of data in the new LV.
```

For SSD, it's possible for the data to be discarded entirely, if you did `lvremove` (with `issue_discards = 1` in your lvmconfig) or `mkfs`.

It's also possible for LVM to use a different data offset, in which case all LVs you attempt to create would be at the wrong offsets, too. Same if the LVM is on a partition, and the partition itself was not re-created at the correct offset.

Logical Volumes can also be allocated any which way (if you had more than one, or resized them). There's no guarantee the data will be available on disk in a single linear block (like a partition).

So in order to restore missing LV, you need detailed knowledge about LVM metadata. For this reason, LVM keeps backups of its metadata in `/etc/lvm/{archive,backup}` - but it won't help if it was already wiped, zeroed or discarded and you're probably lacking these if you formatted over your root partition also. Still, check it anyway, maybe you're lucky.

There's also metadata backup on the Physical Volume itself, but if you pvcreate/vgcreate over it, that's probably already gone too. Still, it does not hurt to check:

```
$ strings -w /dev/disk | grep -A 1000 'Generated by LVM2'
# Generated by LVM2 version 2.02.103(2) (2013-10-04): Thu Oct 31 11:42:36 2013
...
```

And there you might find fragments of allocation information that might be helpful in recovery, either manually or `vgcfgrestore`. (Note the timestamp, you're looking for one from before your accident).

> So is there a way that I can restore my data?

If the LV was on a single disk and not fragmented in any way, and it's still there (not wiped), partition recovery tools like `testdisk` could also be used to restore it - as a regular partition w/o LVM.

Partitions do not support logical addressing so you can only map LV to partition if it's all in one segment physically, not multiple segments mapped together.

If the filesystem itself cannot be recovered, as long as the data was not encrypted, `photorec` might find some individual, unfragmented files (contents only, original filenames and structure lost).